# Square numbers in descending order until 1

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes an argument (integer), and prints out a list of the square numbers in descending order until 1. I want to use recursion instead of list comprehension or loops.
This is my code:

```
def sqr(num):
    mylist = []
    if num == 1 or num == 0:
        mylist.append(num)
        return mylist
    else:
        num = num**2
        mylist.append(num)
        num = num-1
        mylist.append(sqr(num))
    return mylist
```

Now my code generates sublists, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Hint: since your recursive call returns a list, you can not *append* this to the `mylist` of the caller.

Comment: I cannot extend because "'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: You say you want to _print_ the squares, but the code _returns_ them.  Which do you really want?

Comment: Can you give us an example too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the list as an optional argument.

```
def sqr(num, mylist=None):
    mylist = mylist or []
    if num == 1 or num == 0:
        mylist.append(num)
        return mylist
    else:
        mylist.append(num**2)
        num = num-1
        sqr(num, mylist)
    return mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this work would be to pass a empty list into your function along with the number.

```
def get_squares(num, lista):
    if num in (1, 0):
        lista.append(num)
        return lista
    else:
        lista.append(pow(num, 2))
        num -= 1
        return get_squares(num, lista)

number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print(get_squares(number, []))
# [10000, 9801, 9604,... , 36, 25, 16, 9, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your recursive function. **Explanation**: The square of number `n` is appended to the `mylist` defined at the beginning. The function `sqr` is then called again with an argument `n-1`. if `n-1` == `1`, it will append 1 to the function and return the final list without going further to 0 *else* it will keep calling iteratively `sqr` to store the squares of numbers > 1.

```
mylist = []

def sqr(num):
    if num == 1:
        mylist.append(num)
        return mylist # appended list returned if 1 is reached
    else:
        mylist.append(num**2)
        return sqr(num-1) # Recursive call here to sqr()
print (sqr(4))

# [16, 9, 4, 1]
```

Comment: For my personal taste, this function is incomplete because mylist needs to be set empty outside the function

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you want ?

```
def sqr(num,l=[]):
     if num == 1: return l+[num]
     else : return sqr(num-1,l+[num**2])
```

Though, I hope you have in mind that list comprehension will 100s time more efficient and the pythonic way.